# Update nested object using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have the following object. This object gets assigned a new value when the user clicks on a button.

```
state = {
  title: '',
  id: '',
  imageId: '',
  boarding: {
    id: '',
    test: '',
    work: {
      title: '',
      id: ''
    }
  }
}
```

My updated object looks like:

```
state = {
  title: 'My img',
  id: '1234',
  imageId: '5678-232e',
  boarding: {
    id: '0980-erf2',
    title: 'hey there',
    work: {
      title: 'my work title',
      id: '456-rt3'
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to update just work object inside state and keep everything the same. I was using `Object.assign()` when the object was not nested but confused for nesting.

```
Object.assign({}, state, { work: action.work });
```

My action.work has the entire work object but now I want to set that to boarding but this replaces everything that is in boarding which is not what I want.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should manually merge deep object properties, try following:

```
Object.assign({}, state, { 
  boarding: Object.assign({}, state.boarding, {
    work: action.work
  }
});
```

or with spread operator

```
{
  ...state,
  boarding: {
    ...state.boarding,
    work: action.work
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain the role of spread operator in your example and how that is different from your first merge deep prop?

Comment: @fscore I've just found very nice [link](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) on this topic, I believe you would like it!

Comment: @dhilt: the example with spread operator is a good one, but it should be assigned to `state` or to a constant or variable. The way how it's posted is causing an error and confusing it user would use it just as it is 
I would give the example such as: `state = {
  ...state,
  boarding: {
    ...state.boarding,
    work: action.work
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

If merging them manually as @dhilt suggested is not an option, take a look at [lodash's `merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge).

You can use [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) if you want to customise the merge behaviour, e.g. merge arrays instead of overriding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.assign to update nested objects, for example:

```
Object.assign(state.boarding, { work: action.work })
```

This will update the state in place with the new work properties.

Comment: This will NOT return `state`, but `state.boarding`.

Comment: I didn't say it would return it, I said it would update state in place.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. This doesn't even compile in most cases. And even when it does, it has zero effect. Please read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign I'm sorry, but you should delete this answer as it's completely wrong. I'm going to downvote it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**> Use JavaScript spread operator:**

```
{ ...user, staff_information: { nid: e.target.value }
```