# How can I set a particular userId inside my users object on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am mocking a userId which should be saved inside the `users` object of the `reactions` object when a certain icon is clicked inside my react component.

Below is a function `updateUploadReaction` that is supposed to do that for me. So, when the icon is clicked and a particular userId does not exist, it sets it inside the `user` object and adds 1, on clicking again it sets it to false and subtracts 1. So far, this is what I have, I need a guide on exactly how to do that.

reaction object

```
{

        reactions: {
            dislike: {
                count: 0,
                users: {},
            },
            like: {
                count: 0,
                users: {},
            },
            maybe: {
                count: 0,
                users: {},
            },
        },

}
```

function

```
function updateUploadReaction(id, type, uploads) {
    const updatedUploads = new Map([...uploads.entries()]);
    const upload = updatedUploads.get(id);
    const userId = uuid();

    uploads.forEach(() => {
        if (//check if userId exists) {
            upload.reactions[type].count += 1;
            upload.reactions[type].users.(// user Id value) = true;
        } else {
            upload.reactions[type].count -= 1;
            upload.reactions[type].users.(// user Id value) = false;
        }
    });

    updatedUploads.set(id, upload);

    return updatedUploads;
}
```

Comment: `users: []` must be an array not object

Comment: firstly you want to store mutiple or single value in users?

Comment: it could be single or multiple, ie as many users as have reacted. At this particular instant just one user

Comment: check this also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761718/update-nested-object-using-object-assign

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you can't do it the same way you do it with `type` using the `[]` syntax?

`.users[userId] = true`

Comment: But what if she want only object of users?

Comment: According to the comment placed inside the code it looks like they want a key-value system where they can set certain userId's to true or false.

Comment: This keeps adding 3 now when I click the icon.